# How to run Catalyst/Paraview code examples?

Tags: python, catalyst, hpc, paraview

Hi I'm trying to figure out catalist and Paraview for a while. I tried to run these examples on my Paraview but without success.
https://github.com/Kitware/ParaViewCatalystExampleCode
I imagined at least the python code would run with the python shell. But it doesn't seem to work either. I viewed all the kitware tutorials and some others online. But still no progress. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What kind of error do you get?

Comment: I want to know if these are supposed to run by themselves;e.g: Examples show c,c++ etc examples. Should I run these as normal c c++ codes without having to do any configurations on paraview or catalist?

Comment: Now I get an error saying no module called vtkParallelPython              Other python scripts in that folder didn't give any error but I didn't get any output either. If you can explain the basic process of how to run these codes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to run all of the non-Python examples with CTest (i.e. ctest executable). I would suggest running CTest with the -v flag to get verbose output. This will show the command line used to run the examples. For the PythonFullExample, you can just run that with `pvpython`. Note that many of the executables take in a ParaView Catalyst Python script as a command line argument.

Comment: Thanks, I built and ran cTest on Fortran90Example. (It failed though)I want to write a co-processing code based on catalyst for a Fortran simulation. I read the paraview-catalyst userguide, but is there any other link that I can refer?

Comment: The ParaView Catalyst User's Guide has recently been updated to version 2. It is at http://www.paraview.org/paraview-downloads/download.php?submit=Download&version=v4.3&type=data&os=all&downloadFile=ParaViewCatalystUsersGuide_v2.pdf. Also, you may want to look at the FortranPoissonSolver example in the listed github site.

Comment: @andybauer The current version of Catalyst Tutorial includes some info about building Catalyst and its examples. I think it will be useful if you could put some information regarding running the examples.