# Paraview Build in VS

Tags: paraview

I´m trying to build paraview from source, therefore using:

- Windows 7
- Visual Studio 2010
- Qt 4.8.7
- Python 2.7.8
- msmpi 7
- paraview source, version 5.1.0

In CMake I can choose different options to specify what functionality to include into the build process. I tried different combinations, like setting BUILD_EXAMPLES or PARAVIEW_USE_MPI, respectively. Now I have got following questions:

1. When I set BUILD_SHARED_LIBS and PARAVIEW_ENABLE_PYTHON as well (besides others), configuring and generating the project with CMake is successful, but compiling in VS fails; it keeps freezing right after starting the compilation. Did anybody experience the same problem and how did you solve it? (By the way, if I unset BUILD_SHARED_LIBS it works, but I don´t want a static build of Paraview).
2. By using the combination BUILD_EXAMPLES, BUILD_TESTING, PARAVIEW_BUILD_QT_GUI, PARAVIEW_ENABLE_CATALYST, PARAVIEW_ENABLE_PYTHON and PARAVIEW_USE_MPI the same problem as described in 1.) occurs, but that is more or less what I need to use Catalyst to perform in-situ analysis of my FEM simulation. (Incidentally, if I unset BUILD_TESTING in the above combination it works, but I need CTest to test the Catalyst examples as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416630/how-to-run-catalyst-paraview-code-examples). Does anybody now how to fix that problem?
3. As shown at [GitHub](https://github.com/Kitware/ParaViewCatalystExampleCode-MOVED-), some examples have been updated to work properly in Paraview 4.4. Is my version of Paraview (5.1.0) unsuitable for the Catalyst examples? Is that the reason why VS is always hanging up for particular variable settings in CMake and which version of Paraview is most suitable to get the Catalyst examples going?

I'd appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

That's odd! There's no known reason for this. Although I haven't used VS2010 explicitly, we do have dashboards testing with 2013 and I build with VS2015 with no issue.

I'd recommend using the [Ninja](https://ninja-build.org/) as the builder rather than the IDE, however. Just run `cmake-gui.exe` from appropriate VS studio command prompt and pick Ninja as the build generator. Then, to build, just run `ninja` in the build directory.